# How to install and work with jQuery Chosen plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, jquery-chosen

I downloaded jQuery's Chosen plugin, copied the **chosen.min.css** and **chosen.jquery.min.js** files in my project.

Copied link paths in my CSHTML:

```
<link href="~/Content/Bootstrap/css/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Content/Bootstrap/js/chosen.jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have a dropdown list in my CSHTML, somewhat this way:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="btn-group pull-left">
          <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-md set-border" data-toggle="dropdown" id="dropdownbtn">
              <span class="spn-action">Add new criteria</span><span class="caret" id="caretAdjustment"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="chzn-select" role="menu">
              @foreach(var item in Model)
              {
                 <li onclick="ShowMessage('@item.Criteria')"><a href="#">@item.Criteria</a></li>
              }  
           </ul>
      </div>
</div>
```

My jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $("#chzn-select").as(Chosen).chosen();
        });
    });
</script>
```

But nothing as expected by 'Chosen' happens... Where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you realize that `chosen` needs a `select` element?

Comment: And did you include jQuery script?

Comment: `$.as()` ? Can't find that in jQuery's doc, never seen that. What does your console say?

Comment: @Alex-Can it not work in my project without select?

Comment: No, Chosen acts on select elements. First line of [its doc](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) : "Chosen is a jQuery plugin that makes long, unwieldy _select_ boxes much more user-friendly."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) you need a select element:

```
<select data-placeholder="Choose a country..." style="width:350px;" multiple class="chosen-select">
```

And after in js:

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen();
```

Check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexChariz/fosb6meu/) too.

Comment: What do you mean by adding `id="chosen-without-empty"` attribute to the `<select>` tag in your fiddle?

Comment: Can we add this `.chosen` plugin when I Click on any element? @alex-char